# In JSF, how to update a page dynamically and partially with ajax and with out form validation?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, bean-validation, ajax4jsf

I have a JSF 2 form like this:

```
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
<a4j:repeat value="#{dialog.departments}" var="depart">
        <h:inputText value="#{depart.name}"/>
        <h:selectOneRadio value="#{depart.hasSubdepartment}">
           <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" immediate="true"/>
           <f:selectItem itemValue="#{true}"/>
           <f:selectItem itemValue="#{false}"/>
        </h:selectOneRadio>

    <a4j:repeat  value="#{depart.subdepartments}" var="sub" rendered="#{depart.hasSubdepartment}">
        <h:inputText value="#{sub.name}"/>
        <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
    </a4j:repeat>
</a4j:repeat>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

I have simply the form. As you could see, this form displays data structure of departments like a tree.
What I want to implements is that if user switch the radio button to `true`, the sub-departments will be displayed, if switch to false,  the sub-departments will be hidden. 
The problem is that:

- If the `execute` value of the `f:ajax` tag is set to `@form`, the validation of the backing beans such as `@NotNull` and `@Size` will be called. But we don't want to call the validation now since we do not want to save the data now.
- If the `execute` value of the `f:ajax` tag is set to `@this`, it seems that the after the ajax request, the value of the radio reverts. For example, if the radio value is `false`, and we click `true`, then after the ajax request, the value go back to `false`, and the sub-department part is not rendered. This will not happen if `execute` is set to `@form`.

Thanks very much if you have any idea or hint.

Comment: Have you tried the solution outside the first `ui:repeat` replacing `<a4j:repeat value="#{dialog.departments}" var="depart">` with `<ui:param name="depart" value="#{dialog.departments[0]}" />`? This way you would know, if `a4j:repeat` is the reason or whether there are other issues, too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Richfaces integrated testing environment, however I've achieved what you want in plain JSF (that's why it could be an ajax4jsf specific issue). Here you have a test case which works and follows [SSCCE standards](http://sscce.org/). Tested with **Mojarra 2.1.26** & **Tomcat 6**:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head />

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <ui:repeat value="#{dialog.departments}" var="depart">
                <h:inputText value="#{depart.name}" />
                <h:selectOneRadio value="#{depart.hasSubdepartments}">
                    <f:ajax render="@form" immediate="true" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{true}" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{false}" />
                </h:selectOneRadio>

                <h:panelGroup id="subdepartmentPanel"
                    rendered="#{depart.hasSubdepartments}">
                    <ui:repeat value="#{depart.subdepartments}" var="sub">
                        <h:inputText value="#{sub.name}" />
                    </ui:repeat>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </ui:repeat>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Dialog {

    public class Department {
        private String name;

        private List<Department> subdepartments = new ArrayList<Dialog.Department>();

        private boolean hasSubdepartments;

        public Department(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public List<Department> getSubdepartments() {
            return subdepartments;
        }

        public boolean isHasSubdepartments() {
            return hasSubdepartments;
        }

        public void setHasSubdepartments(boolean hasSubdepartments) {
            this.hasSubdepartments = hasSubdepartments;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setSubdepartments(List<Department> subdepartments) {
            this.subdepartments = subdepartments;
        }
    }

    private List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<Dialog.Department>();

    public Dialog() {
        // Create departments and subdepartments
        departments.add(new Department("First Department"));
        Department d = new Department("Second department");
        d.getSubdepartments().add(new Department("Subdepartment"));
        departments.add(d);
    }

    public List<Department> getDepartments() {
        return departments;
    }

}
```